# UNIX Pipe System with Reading and Writing to Execute "ls -la" Command

Tags: c++, unix, pipe

These are the instructions for the code: A program named mp2_part6.cpp which starts the command ”ls -la” using a fork() followed by an exec() (any of the exec functions will work). Use a UNIX pipe system call to send the output of ls -la back to the parent, read it using the read() function, and then write it to the console using the write() function. Note: the pipe will not work if you do not close and/or redirect the correct file descriptors. It’s up to you to figure out which ones those need to be.

This is what I have so far. I am not sure why it is not printing out the correct output.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <iostream>

char *cmd1[] = { "/bin/ls -la", 0 };

int main()
{

    int fd[2], nbytes;

    char string[] = "ls -la";
    char readbuffer[80];

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) { // child writes to pipe

        // open the pipe, call exec here, write output from exec into pipe

        close(fd[0]); // read not needed

        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);

        write(fd[1], cmd1[0], strlen(cmd1[0])+1);        

        exit(0);
    }
    else { // parent reads from pipe

        // read output from pipe, write to console

        close(fd[1]); // write not needed

        nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

        std::cout << readbuffer << std::endl;
        execl(readbuffer, (char*)NULL);

        close(fd[0]);
        write(1, readbuffer, nbytes);        
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly let me tell you what I interpreted from the question:

> The child will execute `exec()` and the output of `ls -la` should be printed by the parent using pipe.

According to this I fixed your code to give the output of `ls -la`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

char *cmd1[] = { "ls", "-la", NULL }; 
//for exec each parameter should be a separate string

int main()
{    

    int fd[2], nbytes;

    //char string[] = "ls -la"; //unused variable
    char readbuffer[80]; // is a buffer size of 80 enough?

    pipe(fd);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) { // child writes to pipe

        // open the pipe, call exec here, write output from exec into pipe

        dup2(fd[1],1); // stdout goes to fd[1]
        close(fd[0]); // read not needed

        execvp(cmd1[0],cmd1); //execute command in child

        exit(0);
    }    
    else { // parent reads from pipe

        // read output from pipe, write to console

        close(fd[1]); // write not needed

        //read the output of the child to readbuffer using fd[0]
        nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));

        //std::cout << readbuffer << std::endl;
        //write also outputs readbuffer
        //output readbuffer to STDOUT
        write(1, readbuffer, nbytes);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: You interpreted that correctly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: A up-vote would do great. And thanks for marking as the answer.